# Django: assign foreignkey field with object?

Tags: django, django-models

**models.py**

```
class Order(TimeStampedModel): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Payment(TimeStampedModel): 
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        'orders.Order',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        unique=True,
    )
```

What I want to do is to create `Payment` first and add it to `Order`.

Let say `Order` is already created without `payment` field.

**<1>**

```
In [1]: order = Order.objects.first()

In [2]: payment = Payment.objects.create()

In [3]: order.payment = payment

In [4]: order.save()
```

**<2>**

```
In [7]: order.payment_set.add(payment)
```

I'd like to know what is difference between **<1>** and **<2>**. Which one is a right way?

Answer (score 2):

Your first example can be rewritten to reduce DB usage (as it is currently presented, it will make `INSERT` with `payment=NULL`, followed by an `UPDATE`). This should be better:

```
order = Order.objects.first()
payment = Payment.objects.create(order=order)
```

Now, to the question. Both approaches are almost identical. However, there are differences if you are using django >= 1.9. [`.add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/) now performs bulk inserts by default instead of calling `save` on each instance. This means that if you have any signals like `post_save` or `post_create` connected to your `Payment` model, you won't have them executed unless you explicitly specify `bulk=False`:

```
 order.payment_set.add(payment, bulk=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have your relation the wrong way around your first scenario; lines 3 and 4 should be:

```
payment.order = order
payment.save()
```

**1. Setting FK on an instance.**

The save method of your Payment is called and you are associating a single Payment with a single Order. Payment.save is called, firing save related signals.

**2: Using the [RelatedManager.add method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add).**

You can actually add multiple associations at once using this method. So for example you could associate multiple Payments with the one Order using:

```
order.payment_set.add(payment_1, payment_2, ... payment_N)
```

Importantly, by default since Django 1.9, the Payments are created without their save() method being called, so you will not get save related signals firing.

**On the importance of save signals firing:**

It's very common to use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch) in Django applications. They provide a powerful way to add functionality to your application without cluttering up your model logic. If your application is using them, bewaring adding associations using the RelatedManager.add approach, as the save related signals will not fire.